# Can I pass a base class type as a generic parameter to an interface

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics, interface

Can I pass base class types as a generic parameters to interfaces which are implemented in the context of the successors of that base class in C#.

Let's imagine there is an interface:

```
public interface IElement<T>
{
   Collection<T> Neighbors { get; }   
}
```

I want to implement this interface like this:

```
public class Element : IElement<object>
{
   public Collection<Neighbor> Neighbors { get; set; }
}
```

I also even tried achieving it like this:

```
public class Element : IElement<IObject>
{
   public Collection<Neighbor> Neighbors { get; set; }
}
```

Where IObject and Neighbor are:

```
public interface IObject
{ 
}

public class Neighbor : IObject
{
   // some props
}
```

**In either way I get the same error:** Element does not implement the IElement interface - member Neighbors cannot implement IElement.Neighbors, because they have different return types.

The purpose of this is to make an abstraction of the datatypes and use a simpler version of them in the business logic:

```
public class BusinessLogic
{
   bool predicate1;
   bool predicate2;
    
   // variant 1
   public bool CanIDoSomething(IElement<object> element)
   {
      return element.Neighbours.Any() && predicate1 && predicate2;
   }

   // variant 2
   public bool CanIDoSomething(IElement<IObject> element)
   {
      return element.Neighbours.Any() && predicate1 && predicate2;
   }
}
```

The problem goes even deeper if I try to use IEnumerable instead of Collection:

```
public interface IElement<T>
{
   IEnumerable<T> Neighbors { get; }   
}
```

What am I missing and is there a workaround for this?

---

### ***EDIT:***

I Made the IElement interface generic parameter covariant as follows:

```
public interface IElement<out T>
{
   IEnumerable<T> Neighbors { get; }
}
```

But this does not solve the interface implementation error.

The only way I can make the class to implement the interface correctly is by doing this:

```
public class Element : IElement<IObject>
{
   public Collection<Neighbor> Neighbors { get; set; }

   IEnumerable<IObject> IElement<IObject>.Neighbors => Neighbors;
}
```

Is there a limitation that causes the covariance to not be applied implicitly when implementing an interface?

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

I want to keep the `IObject` interface instead of using `object` directly because in the `IObject` interface if I ever need I can place a certain subset of the properties of the `Neighbor` class.

Comment: `IElement<T>.Neighbors` must be of type `Collection<T>`, so `IElement<object>.Neighbors` must be of type `Collection<object>` and as you can guess `Collection<Neighbor>` is not inherited from `Collection<object>`

Comment: [Yes you can with the proper keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance), but that's not what your code is trying to do.  What's the point of `IElement<object>` ? When you specify `IObject` as the concrete type, `Collection<Neighbor>` means you're actually trying to return a *specific derived* type, when the interface says that any derived type could be returned

Comment: You can control covariance and contravariance with the `in` and `out` keywords but I suspect a simpler design of your class hierarchy would be better.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` has covariant generic parameter `T`, `Collection<T>` is invariant (as any other class). You can make `T` in `IElement` covariant as well, like  `IElement<out T>` and play around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Original scenario with `Collection<T>`

You get this error, because your `IElement<T>` interface has a generic type parameter `T` and the property `Neighbors` is of type `Collection<T>`. Hence, your `Element` type that implements `IElement` with the concrete type `object` needs to implement a `Collection<object>` not a `Collection<Neighbor>`. This property must be `public`, as it is implemented from your public interface and the default member visibility in a `class` is `private`. The same applies if you replace `object` with `Neighbor` or any other type. See this example for `Neighbor`.

```
public class Element : IElement<Neighbor>
{
    public Collection<Neighbor> Neighbors { get; set; }
}
```

While this resolves your original your error, you will not be able to pass instances of type `Element` to your method `CanIDoSomething`, because your type parameter `T` in `IElement<T>` is [invariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance), which means you can only use the originally specified type. In the example this type would be `Neighbor` and not `IObject` or `object`.

You need to make your type parameter [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) in order to use a more derived type like `Neighbor`. However, you will run into the issue that `Collection<T>` uses an invariant type parameter as well, so you will need to replace it with a type that has a covariant type parameter like `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`. The example below will show you how covariance works for your case. You can start from there to use other types and collections.

### Scenario with generics and `IEnumerable<T>`

If you want your `IElement<T>` to be generic and use `IEnumerable<T>`, declare your interface with a convariant type parameter using the keyword `out`.

```
public interface IElement<out T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Neighbors { get; }
}
```

Then implement it in your concrete class with the correct type, e.g. `Neighbor`.

```
public class Element : IElement<Neighbor>
{
    public IEnumerable<Neighbor> Neighbors { get; }
}
```

You can keep both of your `CanIDoSomething` methods as they are, because `Neighbor` is derived from `object` and implements the `IObject` interface, so it will work with covariance in both cases.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have misleadingly omitted the public access specifiers in order to keep the examples simpler.

The problem is the properties return types.

Could you please take a look again at the **Edit** section of my question? I think the problem is as you have already mentioned 
" `Collection<T>` uses an invariant type parameter as well..."

Why `public IEnummerable<IObject> IElement<IObject>.Neighbors => Neighbors;` is valid, but at the same time `public Collection<Neighbor> Neighbors { get; set; }` is not enough to implement `IElement<IObject>` by it self?

Comment: @D.Ivanov That is because your interface `IElement<out T>` defines a property `Neighbors` of type `IEnummerable<T>` and not `Collection<T>` and that is what you need to implement. This property can return a `Collection<T>`, because it implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so it can be assigned. In other words, you have to expose the `Neighbors` property as an `IEnumerable<T>`, if you back it internally with a list or a collection is up to you in your concrete class.

Comment: Thank you very much!